# How I can change render to return json in view Django

Tags: python, django

I have function in view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import myModel

def articleTheme(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article_id = request.POST['id']
        article = myModel.objects.get(id=article_id)
        theme = article.theme
        return render(request, 'theme.html', {'newTheme': theme })
```

now it works normal. But I have excess html. I want return json object.
What I can import and return?

Answer (score 9):

Use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
..
def articleTheme(request):
    ..
    return JsonResponse({'newTheme': theme })
```

Comment: And then how to access this in next view function?.

Comment: How does the template load??

Answer (score 0):

You can return the data with `HttpResponse` and in JSON format like this:

```
data = {'newTheme': theme}
data = json.dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
return HttpResponse(data)
```